# Accessing List Items in html list using ID

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access particular item in an unordered list in HTML I have following

```
<ul id="listid">
    <li id=first>first element</li>
    <li id=second>second element</li>
    <li id=third>.....</li>
</ul>
```

I want to access particular element, how can I access by using its ID in javascript.

Comment: `document.getElementById(...)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck! More: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score -1):

Since ID is already defined. You may select the ID using:

```
var firstItem = document.getElementById("first");
```